# Convert .ai to .png?

Tags: images, gimp, png, image-conversion

I just downloaded a free vector graphics set which contained UI elements and icons. The button graphics have some text on them. It were, however, .ai files which are not familiar to me.

Obviously, I did a search on Google. It turned out that:

- you can open .ai files with Adobe Reader. Great, I could take a screenshot from there, but I cannot remove the texts on the graphics as I'm using *Reader*...
- you can import it in GIMP but then the text and graphics are blent together which means I cannot remove the text either.

Is there a way to easily convert .ai to .png without too much clutter and so that the text isn't put on the images? I only need the background of the buttons, i.e. not the text like 'Test' which is just put on it to show how it looks with text.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ai2svg.py](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools#ai2svg.py) to convert the `ai` file to `svg`, then open and edit the result in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

---

Inkscape might be able to open the files directly as well, but you might need additional software.

Comment: I installed Inkscape and it could import them directly, thanks!

Comment: Inkscape import formats: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_formats_can_Inkscape_import.2Fexport.3F